# How can I return a div from forEach inside map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a new component in React to display filters. My filter data looks like this:

```
{countries: [0: {value: 'England'}, 1: {value: 'Australia'}], continents: []}
```

In my render function I want to return a div for each value inside an object (England, Australia). Currently, I don't get anything rendered to the Dom.

```
render() {
        const {i18n, t} = this.props;
    
        return <div className={'filter'}>
            <ul className={'filter-list'}>
                {
                    Object.keys(this.props.filters).map(i => {
                        this.props.filters[i].forEach(
                            element => {
                                console.log('element', element)
                                return <p>{element.value}</p>
                            }
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>;
    }
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve this/return the value properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` does not return anything. You'll need to use `map` instead:

```
{
  Object.keys(this.props.filters).map((i) => {
    // Switched to .map and added `return`
    return this.props.filters[i].map((element) => {
      return <p>{element.value}</p>;
    });
  });
}
```

This code will create a 2 dimensional array of elements, but react supports that.

Comment: Oh wow, I actually didn't know that forEach doesn't return anything :facepalm:... thanks so much! I will accept the answer as soon as I can